# Fastlane doesn't see cocoapods action

Tags: ios, cocoapods, fastlane

I'm trying to add pods installation in fastlane scripts.

In my **Fastfile**:

```
desc "Install cocoapods"
lane :install_pods do
  cocoapods(
    use_bundle_exec: false
)
end
```

When I'm running `$ fastlane install_pods`

I'm getting this error message:

> Could not find action, lane or variable 'cocoapods'. Check out the
> documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions

If I'm running `$ fastlane run cocoapods`, as described in doc from link above, I'm getting the same issue.

CocoaPods installed by gem, so when I call manually `pod install` Pods installing correctly.

Please help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my **Fastfile** I had lane like this for **pad install**

```
desc "Install cocoapods"
lane :install_pods do
  cocoapods(
      clean: true,
      use_bundle_exec: false
)
end
```

and running this

> $ fastlane install_pods

command in terminal is working fine for me.